# Windows command line script for deleting files newer than a certain time, recursively

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Can anyone help me with a windows command line script that recurses through a target directory and deletes files newer than the specified date and time stamp?

I've tried the `forfiles` command, but it doesn't allow me to specify the **time**, it only allows me to specify a date.

I think the only option is probably to use a `FOR` statement, but I'm so new to the command line that I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Save it as **Delete_Files.bat**
And execute it as

**cmd>** Delete_Files.bat MM-DD-YYYY

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('xcopy *.* /d:%1 /L /I null') do if exist "%%~nxa" del "%%~nxa"
```

Comment: thanks djadmin, could you perhaps explain what each  part of that script does?

Comment: also, wheres the part where i specify the target directory to recurse through?

i don't know what the wildcard will do, the variables, or the switches

Comment: Code iterates over all the files in a particular location ie. 'd:' and finds for the particular DATE which is passed as a parameter. If the date is newer it will delete using 'del'.

Answer (score -1):

Where do you specify the location to run the script against? I ran the same one as above and it deleted everything in the same directory as where the Delete_files.bat was kept